# PHP infinite loop results no repeated but updates

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I'm creating a background process using PHP but I intended to test it out using `while(1)` to execute it infinitely. The results were shown but it repeats the result like:

```
Result 1
text: Hi!
Result 2
text: Hello!
Result 1
text: Hi!
Result 2
text: Hello!
```

What I don't know to do is that it doesn't repeat but it will be updated when something changes the value like:

Initial run:

```
Result 1
text: Hi!
Result 2
text: Hello!
```

When there is a change:

```
Result 1
text: Hello!
Result 2
text: Hello!
```

The scenario above are just examples but the script is connected to a database.

Update: My code.

```
<?php

    @ini_set("output_buffering", "Off");
    @ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
    @ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
    @ini_set('max_execution_time',1200);

    require("database.php");

    while(1){
        $sqlReports = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE reports.process = 'F'";

        $resReports = odbc_exec($conn,$sqlReports);

        while($reports = odbc_fetch_array($resReports))
        {
            echo $reports['reportnum']. "</br>";

            $sqlStations = "SELECT * FROM stations";

            $resStations = odbc_exec($conn,$sqlStations);

            while($stations = odbc_fetch_array($resStations))
            {
                echo $stations['name']. "</br>";
            }

            sleep(1);
            flush();
            ob_flush();     
        }
    }

?>
```

Result of the code:

```
1
station1
station2
station3
2
station1
station2
station3
3
station1
station2
station3
1
station1
station2
station3
2
station1
station2
station3
...
```

I wanted is that it will not display again the displayed number but it will update if there are changes like:

No update during the loop:

```
1
station1
station2
station3
2
station1
station2
station3
3
station1
station2
station3
```

Updated during the loop:

```
1
station1
station2
station5
2
station6
station2
station3
3
station7
station8
station9
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Some code?

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried so far

Comment: From where do you get this data? db? Why do you use a while loop and not a cronjob?

Comment: sorry to include the code :) wait ill update... i will not use cron because im on windows which will be task scheduler. but i'm testing it out using `while 1` loop

Comment: *not include the code

Comment: SELECT * FROM reports WHERE reports.process = 'F' is returning two rows so you will get it for tow times

Comment: check the echo count($sqlReports); and say

Comment: kindly check my intended outcome thanks!

Comment: what are you trying ?

Comment: Is it possible for a pure php script to display a view on what I updated above with an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the output you are expecting it seems like you would like to skip the stations part if it has all the same stations as earlier run of script.

To achieve such think you

Either need to store the state of stations into a temporary storage and next time when you are running script again you can look into temporary storage and compare if there is a change or not, that way you can take your decision on either to include station part or not.

or

You can have some flag at station level which indicates the station entry is new for a particular report, and if you find any such new station you can include the station else you can skip it.

Comment: the changes depends from the database. and the original code of it is that the data will be stored on a temp table in which i didn't included on the example above.

Comment: what i wanted to know is how to present it on the view side as what i posted above? then if it is not possible on pure php then i'll go on using ajax with the settimeout :P

Comment: If you data stored into a temp table you now can fetch station data related to report stored in previous run and you also have all station data via your query on _stations_ table, now you can compare two set of data and take your decision.

Comment: @BLNK I thought you are running the script as a cron, If you are struggling with presenting it on a web front, could you please explain how you are presenting your data currently and for what you need fetch updates, that will help a lot in answering.

Comment: no I was running it on a `while(1)` loop to run the script continuously. but i up vote for reminding to use a flag trigger.

Comment: If it is not a cron script, I hope you have handled exit condition carefully. I am not getting why do you want to run your script continuously. If you have web front then it can request server for changes and on server script you just need to look into data to find out if there is a change or not. Or using socket your server notify client if there is update in data, you can think about making your application real time where server sends data to client. may be that can solve problem you are facing at displaying data updates.